# Prevent Process Builder action from firing when lookup field is blank

Tags: flow, process-builder, criteria

I have a process, based on the case object, with very simple criteria that launches a flow. I need to be able to prevent the process from launching the flow  when the case record does not have the account lookup field populated.

I've tried entering my criteria as "when conditions are met" as well as "formula evaluates to true". In both cases, the flow is still launched despite the AccountId field being null. My current formula is:

NOT ( ISNULL ( [Case].AccountId ) )

In case you're wondering why we have cases that do not have an account specified, we use the email-to-case feature in Salesforce. If there is no matching contact for the email, the case is created without a contact and account.

Any ideas on how I can prevent the process from launching the flow when the account lookup field is blank?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about isBlank() instead of isNull()?

isBlank([Case].AcccountId) = false

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000ssJHAAY